# Remover parametros Select2

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

Estou com um problema utilizando o plugin Select2, eu necessito fazer uma requisição AJAX, mas preciso que a URL final seja a seguinte:

```
api/user/findbyname/name
```

E a forma que está vindo é esta:

```
api/user/findbyname/?q=name&_=1395243972884
```

O meu código está desta forma

```
ajax: {
    url: "/api/user/findbyname/",
    params: {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (term) {
        return {
            q: term                    
        };
    },
    results: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está fazendo isso com um `form`?

Comment: Não é um input text na tela mesmo, e não está dentro de um form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Select2 usa o `ajax` do jQuery por baixo dos panos. Quando você usa `data` ele coloca o resultado na query string [em um `GET`; no `POST` ele iria para o corpo da requisição], tal como [o método original](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Se você quer esse resultado na própria URL (i.e. no `path`), a solução "natural" seria colocá-lo no campo `url`:

```
ajax: {
    url: "/api/user/findbyname/" + term,
```

E deixar o `data` vazio. Entretanto, creio que para para isso você não poderá usar o `ajax` dessa forma, e sim fazer a requisição explicitamente, usando `query`. Dei uma lida rápida [na documentação](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) e [nesse exemplo](https://gist.github.com/techniq/4609063), mas não entendi 100% como ela funciona, mas de qualquer forma sugiro começar por aí. Minha tentativa de solução (não testada) seria:

```
query: function(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/user/findbyname/" + query.term,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Usando esta propriedade `query`funcionou, depois tive que fazer no success o `options.callback` para conseguir trabalhar com os resultados nas outras propriedades do plugin.

Comment: @fbadaro Tem razão, esse detalhe me passou despercebido. O exemplo linkado usa `query.callback` - não sei se é a mesma coisa...

Comment: Sim sim, é que no meu caso eu montei um objeto options, com as propriedades da minha query. Tks

Answer (score -1):

Esse plugin vem por padrão com metodo get o que causa isso na URl, trocando pelo metodo post imagino que o problema se resolva, mas é apenas um palpite.

```
 ajax: {
 type: 'POST',
 url: "/api/user/findbyname/",
 params: {
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 data: function (term) {
    return {
        q: term                    
    };
 },
 results: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Trocar o método de `GET` para `POST` de fato fará com que os parâmetros saiam da query string e vão para o corpo da requisição. Mas não é isso que o OP quer: ele precisa que o termo de busca esteja no `path` da URL.